# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, ethereum, aws-security-group, connection-refused

I am running an eth node (prysm) on an ec2 which the api data is accessible through port 3500. I have made the ec2 inbound security traffic publicly accessible to all traffic to query the api from anywhere.

However, the api seems to be only accessible internally through 0.0.0.0:3500, whenever I am trying to access the api publicly through the ec2 ipv4 address (e.g http://3.10.45.65:3500/eth/v1alpha1/beacon/chainhead <-dummy link) i ran into the error `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.

Just to make sure the ec2 was configured well, I hosted a dummy page publicly using python http server through port 3500 which was functioning well and was publicly accessible.

I am a lil confused to what else could be blocking the server from handling the request.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a reverse proxy server such as caddy (https://caddyserver.com/docs/quick-starts/reverse-proxy) which redirected the queries back to the localhost and it worked. Nevertheless, try to keep your ip private